# Calculated field won't evaluate correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2010, office-2010

Ok I have a table on a worksheet which has some columns for some calculations

```
PPS | Qty | TtlPrice | Comm | Fee | Ttl | format
```

**Column Definitions**

- PPS - straight `Numeric(9,5)`
- Qty - straight `Numeric(12,0)`
- ttlPrice - `PPS * Qty`
- Comm - Standard flat rate
- Fee - `=IF([@PPS] > 1, -SUM(0.005 * [@Qty]), 0)`
- Ttl - `=SUM([@TtlPrice]:[@Fee])`
- format - Conditional formatting control column

Problem is that when I evaluate the `Fee` column it actually does the inverse of what you would think. Any value above `1` is evaluated as `True` in the conditional clause section which then evaluates `-Sum(.005*[@Qty])` instead of `0` and the vice is true, any PPS less than `1` is evaluated to `False`.

Is there a quirk that i havent noticed before when dealing with row reference in tables of Excel that would cause this nature?

Comment: See @Gimp's answer. To expand more, the `IF` formula works like this: `IF Condition is True, Then, Else` , so as written above, your Fee formula says `**IF** the value in PPS is greater than 1, **THEN** negate the product of the quantity value *.005, **ELSE** 0`

Comment: damn your right, been looking at greater than and less thans too much today....gotta love the minor syntactical problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this for your fee?

```
=IF([@PPS] > 1, 0, -SUM(0.005 * [@Qty]))
```

Your question's confused me a bit, so please comment if i'm missing something and i'll revise/ delete my answer.

Comment: The problem is that i am getting the inverse of the logic.  If the `PPS` value is `Less than 1` it should result in the negative calculation.  If the value is `greater than 1` then it should result in a 0.